# CSS text transition reverting to font size after finished

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having issues transitioning my text properly. I have a list with five hyperlink texts:

```
<div id="listContainer">
<ul id="wordList">
    <li class="wordListItem"><a class="wordListLink" href="somewhere1.jsp">Word1</a></li>
    <li class="wordListItem"><a class="wordListLink" href="somewhere2.jsp">Word2</a></li>
    <li class="wordListItem"><a class="wordListLink" href="somewhere3.jsp">Word3</a></li>
    <li class="wordListItem"><a class="wordListLink" href="somewhere4.jsp">Word4</a></li>
    <li class="wordListItem"><a class="wordListLink" href="somewhere5.jsp">Word5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I use the #wordList to remove the bullets, the #wordListItem to display the words inline, and the #wordListLink to do the text transitions and font properties:

```
.wordListLink{
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.wordListLink:link {
    color: white;
}

.wordListLink:visited {
    color: white;
}

.wordListLink:hover {
    color: #838383;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    /*I've tried font-size: 45px but the transition moves the rest of the words over*/
}
```

And a list container to move the list to the right side:

```
#listContainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to increase the font size a little on hover. But with the transform: scale(1.1) the text increases but once it finishes increasing, it just snaps back to normal, while the mouse is still hovered. It doesn't remain at 1.1 scale for some reason. The problem with using font-size: 45px is that, first, the increasing moves the other words over to make room, and second, it increases the font leftwards and upwards instead of equally on all sides. Anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

The list items are not large enough to accommodate the text when you hover.

You should,

1. increase the `width` of the list items,
2. reduce the `font-size` change (say from `1.35em` to `1.4em`),
3. add a right `margin`.

Let me know, if it helps!

Comment: I tried that but it seems that even with added margin, setting the width larger than the word and lowering the font-size difference, it still moves everything over. I have a feeling that each word needs to be its own element and set in an absolute position so as to not affect anything around it. I'll give that a try. Thank you for the reply!